# Fetching email contacts from Phonebook iOS Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I would want to retrieve email contacts from Phone book from iOS using Swift. This is how I'm doing:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.delegate = self
    contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "emailAddresses.@count > 0")
    present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContacts contacts: [CNContact]) {

    var emailContact = contacts.map { $0.emailAddresses.first!.value as String }
    print(emailContact) //It's actually not returning anything.

}
```

Resultant screen is:
[Resultant Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsmBV.png)

What I would want is to appear it something like:
[Expected resultant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqKQg.png)

I imported `Contacts` and `ContactsUI` and also declared protocol `CNContactPickerDelegate` I really can't figure out why the `didSelectContacts` function is not working.

Answer (score 0):

So I just figured out what was causing the issue. Now It's working fine for me, I was using `didSelectContacts` instead of `didSelect contacts`.
This is letting me select multiple contacts

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
    var emailContact = contacts.map { $0.emailAddresses.first!.value as String }
    print(emailContact) 
    //returns: ["John-Appleseed@mac.com", "kate-bell@mac.com"]
}
```